# How to show without calculator that $\left\lfloor\, \log_{10}{999^{999}}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor\, \log_{10}{999^{999}}+\log_{10}2\right\rfloor$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

By wolfram alpha, I get

$\left\lfloor\, \log_{10}{999^{999}}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor\, \log_{10}{999^{999}}+\log_{10}2\right\rfloor=2996$.

How to prove that $\left\lfloor\, \log_{10}{999^{999}}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor\, \log_{10}{999^{999}}+\log_{10}2\right\rfloor$ without calculator or wolfram alpha?

Thank in advances.

Comment: Am I reading this right? $\log_{10}2$ is not zero, so how can $\log_{10}{999^{999}} = \log_{10}{999^{999}}+\log_{10}2$ be true?

Comment: @Swapnil $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function, i.e. $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the largest integer which is smaller or equal to $x$, e.g. $\lfloor 1.2 \rfloor = \lfloor 1.9 \rfloor = 1$.

Comment: @Three.OneFour Thanks for the clarification. But then isn't the proof of $\left\lfloor\, \log_{10}{999^{999}}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor\, \log_{10}{999^{999}}+\log_{10}2\right\rfloor$ very simple. We only need to prove $\log_{10}2 <1 $.

Comment: @Swapnil No, you also have to show that $\log_{10} 999^{999}$ has a distance greater than $\log_{10} 2$ to the next larger integer. Consider e.g. $0 = \lfloor 0.9 \rfloor \neq \lfloor 0.9 + 0.2 \rfloor = 1$.

Comment: @Three.OneFour Oh, I overlooked that accidentally. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 5):

Prove that:

$$\log_{10}999^{999}+\log_{10}2<\log_{10}1000^{999}=2997$$

In other word:

$$\log_{10}2<\log_{10}1000^{999}-\log_{10}999^{999}=\log_{10}\left(\frac{1000}{999}\right)^{999}$$

so:

$$2<\left(\frac{1000}{999}\right)^{999}=\left(1+\frac{1}{999}\right)^{999}$$

It's true by [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Next we should prove $3 \cdot 999-1=2996<\log_{10}999^{999}$. It's equal:

$$3-\frac{1}{999}<\log_{10}999$$

or:

$$10^{3-\frac{1}{999}}=1000 \cdot 10^{-\frac{1}{999}}<999$$

$$10^{-\frac{1}{999}}<\frac{999}{1000}=\left(1-\frac{1}{1000}\right)$$

$$10^{-1}<\left(1-\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{999}$$

It's also true by Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: Or just take the first terms of the binomial expansion (since all the terms are positive)